# Floating point Truncates to 2 digits in python on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, eclipse-plugin, floating-point

I am trying to Add an Floating point number to Integer value, but the resulting number is truncated to 2 decimal points.
Here is the example:

print 1234567890 + .123

output:  1234567890.12

The same code is working fine in Python shell

> > > 12345678901 + .123

```
12345678901.123
```

If the length of the Integer value is less than 10 then I am getting expected number.

print 123456789.123

output: 123456789.123

Comment: If you care about the appearance of the output, use string formatting instead of `print`ing the value directly (which implicitly converts to `str`). In Python 2.7, the `float.__str__` method converts the internal binary representation to decimal using 12 significant decimal digits, which is what you're seeing here.

Answer (score 1):

The computation in both cases are the same, but used representation is different. Consider the following example with Python2 (2.7.10):

```
>>> a = 1234567890 + .123
>>> a
1234567890.123
>>> print a
1234567890.12
>>> str(a)
'1234567890.12'
>>> repr(a)
'1234567890.123'
```

When Python shell prints result of an expression calculated in it, it emits result of `repr()` for the result. With usual `print`, instead, `str()` is called for any input value which is not a string. Python documentation says:

> The difference with repr(object) is that str(object) does not always attempt to return a string that is acceptable to eval(); its goal is to return a printable string.

So, the question results in: why str() prints less digits, and whether it is important for your task.

As already prompted by @MarkDickinson, str() in Python2 prints up to 12 decimal digits (with trailing 0's cut). However, Python3 (3.4.3) behavior differs - for the same value:

```
>>> a = 1234567890 + .123
>>> a
1234567890.123
>>> print(a)
1234567890.123
```

the difference is that Python3 default float formatting is that it searches for the shortest decimal representation which, when converted back to float, gives exactly the same value. Because `a == float("1234567890.123")`, no more digits are printed. This difference can be more colorfully showed on the following classic example:

Python2:

```
>>> v = 0.1 + 0.2
>>> v
0.30000000000000004
>>> print v
0.3
>>> print 0.30000000000000004
0.3
>>> print 0.3000000000004
0.3
>>> print 0.300000000004
0.300000000004
```

Python3:

```
>>> v = 0.1 + 0.2
>>> v
0.30000000000000004
>>> print(v)
0.30000000000000004
```

so, Python2 stops printing before the problematic digit, but Python3 doesn't.

An explicit formatting request changes this logic for both Python major versions: '%g' and '%f' have default of 6 digits after decimal point, if not overridden and if not switched to exponential format. (Again, trailing zeros aren't printed.) This condition is literally copied from C standard, which formatting print is mimiced by Python library.